# Regex match parenthesis that are not within square braces

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to determine with an expression contains parentheses `(...)`, where the `(...)` are **not** within a square braces. This is for use with parsing and processing some simple lisp style expressions.

I've adapted the following **working** expression that I used to split a string on space characters that are not within square brackets, but I can't seem to achieve the same effect for the above case.

The expression I am using:

```
/(\[.*?\]|(\(.*\)+))/g
```

Here are a list of example expressions with their desired output from a hasPair function.

```
 - (+ 2 2) -> true
 - (+ 2 (- 4 2)) -> true
 - [(+ 2 2)] -> false 
 - [(def i (+ 2 2)] -> false
 - (defn add [+ 2 2]) -> true
 - def add [(+ 2 2)] -> false
 - (defn add x y [(+ x y]) -> true
```

I'm probably missing something obvious, but I can't see what it is.

*(The expressions will always be balanced, if that makes a difference)*

Comment: trying giving more examples since your examples are too simple.

Comment: To add to @Juno's comment, can you add an example of real text you'd be working with, and what the resulting matches should be? Are the square brackets always directly next to the parens?

Comment: May be `^\[\(.+\)^\]`

Comment: @konopko that doesn't seem to match on "(hello)". Juno & Matletics, edit coming up.

Comment: You are right, thats new: `\"^\[?\(.+\)^\]?\"`

Comment: @konopko He didn't mean to include the `"` (those were just used to indicate which example he was referring to), he meant that your regex requires the `[ ]` to be present, so it doesn't match on `(hello)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?:[^[]|^)\(([\w]*)\)(?!\])
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/sDz_kpFTonrp4FWy)

Not really sure what you are looking for but this is what it looks like!

new edit:

```
(?:[^[]|^)?\((.*)\)(?!\])
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/L7fhBXE_owTlKJtc)

edit 3:

```
(?:[^[]|^)\((.*?)\)(?:(?!\]))
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/Chq3xAfPz6Tf_S2L)

Comment: Are you sure you need the `|^`? Looks like it's allowing for a literal `^` there.

Comment: @ajp15243 Yes, it's still 'beginning of string'. Though I can't say for sure if this works for [the cases](http://www.regex101.com/r/bV0iV1) I made up.

Comment: @Jerry That's kind of what I'm pointing out, though. It looks like Debuggex (which is using JavaScript regexes in those links) is treating the `^` in the `|^` part of the expression as a literal `^`, and not as the "start-of-string" meta character. I would expect this behavior, since I would expect the `|` meta character to cause the character to its right to be treated as a literal to fulfill `|`'s purpose of "OR". I am, however, unsure if this is the intended behavior by progenhard. I suspect they were trying to say "OR start-of-string", which is not what that regex seems to be doing.

Comment: @ajp15243 it is working that that it's either A) a character that's not a [ B) the start of the string which will have the case of no characters

Comment: @progenhard Your regex still works because you have a case C) Neither A nor B, because of your `?` to the right of your first non-capturing pattern delimiter (the `(?:[^]]|^)` part) that indicates that the `[^[]` and `^` branches are optional. The Debuggex graph clearly shows this. So you can either go straight into the first `(` character with nothing before it (case C), match a single non-`[` character before the `(` (case A), or match a single literal `^` before the first `(` (case B, which you assert is the start-of-string meta char). That's what the graph shows to me.

Comment: So I threw it into http://www.regexper.com/, and lo and behold, that site says `Start of line`. I was misled by the fact that Debuggex just shows a `^` for what is start-of-line. Also, that's nifty that you can use `^` as a meta char in a `|` statement. You still do have Case C, but that might be intentional. I was a little obsessed over the `^` thing.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try this one:

```
\([^\)]+\)(?![^\[]*\])
```

[regex101 demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/rH3zE8)

This will work only if the square brackets (and parentheses too I think) are balanced.

**EDIT:** Okay, it's a crazy regex now xD

```
\((?:[^\)\[\]]+|(?:[^\[\]\)]*\[[^\[\]\)]*\][^\[\]\)]*))*\)(?![^\[]*\])
```

[regex101 retry](http://www.regex101.com/r/xS3eW7)

Comment: It is likely that `[(...])` is not a valid use case, so you might not have to care about that particular case.

Comment: @ajp15243 Yes, I saw the edit only later. I changed the regex a bit...? xD Itr's really confusing though with all those negated class for `[` and `]`.

Comment: @Jerry that was a typo, fixed now.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but I don't understand what's happening in `(?![^\[]*\])`?

Comment: @DanPrince This prevents cases where the `)` is followed by a `]` (i.e. inside the square brackets) but not if `)` is followed by `[ ]` somewhere ahead. Is this clearer or should I add a paragraph in my answer for more detail? :)

Comment: @Jerry haha this regex is hard it doesn't work for yours also fails with this `[(fasfj])`

Comment: @Jerry: Gotcha, thanks. I hit a input that didn't work though, examples updated.

Comment: @progenhard Huh? It should not match with `[(fasfj])`, at least I think it shouldn't. It's too easy otherwise ;)

Comment: @DanPrince Which one? You mean the nested one? Javascript is not good with nested brackets... If it was a PCRE implementation regex (Perl, PHP), then I would use [this](http://www.regex101.com/r/oL6mF1).

Comment: @DanPrince Otherwise, if you are sure you have at most 1 level of nesting, you can use [this](http://www.regex101.com/r/aH1cK9).

Answer (score 1):

Regexes is but one of many tools, and best suited for certain tasks - this is not one of them.

If the pairs are always balanced, all you really need is to know weather or not a left square bracket precedes a left parentheses in any given string.

This is quite easily achieved by evaluating the following

```
str.indexOf('[') < str.indexOf('(')
```

Comment: I should have been a little clearer, this works if I am just validating, but ultimately I am processing the expression between the braces, doing this as a Regex match returns that straight away, rather than having to validate the string, then find the indexes of the first and last paren to create the appropriate substring.

Comment: Actually the indexOf, even tho done over multiple lines will likely be orders of magnitude faster than the regex that will satisfy your needs. the question is wether code density is a higher priority for you than performance and ease of maintanance. the indexOf/substr route is 2-3 lines of code instead of one, but imo much prefered in this scenario. I love the power regexes, and use them all the time, but sometimes the skill is to know, not to use them ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest keeping things simple here. Consider code below:

```
/\([^)]*\)/.test(str.replace(/\[[^\]]*\]/g, ''));
```

Which solves this task in 2 steps:

1. First phase: replace all `[`...`]` matches by empty string `""`.
2. Second phase: Check whether `(`...`)` is still present in the replaced string.

**`Working Demo: http://ideone.com/aVu9iR`**